# obtener la fecha solo en formato dia/mes/año independiente del idioma de la pc

Tags: javascript

Hola  Actualmente recibo la fecha desde la Bd de esta manera :

Wed Jun 13 2018 17:53:57 GMT-0600 (Hora verano, Montañas (México))

Lo que ya he echo para obtener la fecha en formato mas corto es esto

```
 var fechacorta = val.fechaOriginal.toLocaleString();
```

Y lo que me regresa de la conversión es:

```
2018-6-13 17:53:57
```

Pero esto no cubre del todo mi necesidad, me es necesario mostrar la fecha en formato dia/mes/año

```
13-06-2018 17:53:57
```

Alguien sabe que es lo que puedo implementar para dar solucion??? De antemano muchas gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Esto obtiene la fecha y la retorna en el formato que deseas

Sólo debes poner la fecha que obtienes de la `db` en un `new Date` y obtener los datos que necesitas con los metodos correspondientes, en este caso `getDate() getMonth()` y `getFullYear`

```js
var dateDB = new Date("Wed Jun 13 2018 17:53:57 GMT-0600 (Hora verano, Montañas (México))");

var monthArrayNames = [];
monthArrayNames[0] = "Enero";
monthArrayNames[1] = "Febrero";
monthArrayNames[2] = "Marzo";
monthArrayNames[3] = "Abril";
monthArrayNames[4] = "Mayo";
monthArrayNames[5] = "Junio";
monthArrayNames[6] = "Julio";
monthArrayNames[7] = "Agosto";
monthArrayNames[8] = "Septiembre";
monthArrayNames[9] = "Octubre";
monthArrayNames[10] = "Noviembre";
monthArrayNames[11] = "Diciembre";

var day = dateDB.getDate();
var month = monthArrayNames[dateDB.getMonth()];
var year = dateDB.getFullYear();

var fullDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

console.log(fullDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar varios [métodos del objeto Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) para crear una cadena de texto que se ajuste a tu necesidad. Por ejemplo:

```
let f = new Date("Wed Jun 13 2018 17:53:57 GMT-0600 (Hora verano, Montañas (México))");
let fechaCorta = `${f.getFullYear()}-${f.getMonth() + 1}-${f.getDate()`;
```

De esta manera podrías utilizar la variable `fechaCorta` para mostrar la información en el formato que necesites.

Comment: Te falta el paréntesis para poder ejecutar el método getFullYear

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez con una función para formatear te sea útil.

```
function getDateFormat(otherDateFormat)
{
    var date = new Date(otherDateFormat);

    var day = addZero(date.getDate());
    var month = addZero(date.getMonth()+1);
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hours = addZero(date.getHours());
    var minutes = addZero(date.getMinutes());
    var seconds = addZero(date.getSeconds());

    return [day,month,year].join('-') +' '+ [hours,minutes,seconds].join(':');
}

function addZero(i)
{
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

console.log(getDateFormat('Wed Jun 13 2018 17:53:57 GMT-0600 (Hora verano, Montañas (México))'));
```